# Facebook Login authentication using PHP SDK doesn't work properly?

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

When a user comes to my site, i used to open a new window to authenticate the user and ask for permission through my app(call it as UseCase1). But when a user is already logged-in i was trying to fetch the logged-in user info through PHP SDK so that i need not open a new window and check for the same(You will be avoiding opening a new window that closes after a while since the user is already logged in). But the getUser() method doesn't return me anything. The same method works fine when i go through the UseCase1(open new window which closes automatically).
Below is the code i am trying to use:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => $appId,
                'secret' => $appSecret,
                'oauth' => true
                ));

            $me = $facebook->getUser();
            if ($me) {
              try {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                //code to redirect to login url
                // USECASE1
                // use $facebook->getUser() one USECASE1 is over
                // now the user info is generated properly
              }
            }
```

All the times the user is going through USECASE1(but with an empty window since user is logged in and already authenticated the app) even though he is already logged-in and already authenticated the app previously.

Any idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if the user is getting to 'USECASE1', then it shows that '$me' is being set, because it is getting to your try/catch.

Using `$me = $facebook->getUser();` is not a test for whether a user has accepted permissions for your application yet.

I suspect that the reason for the 'FacebookApiException' Exception being thrown is because you haven't got your user permissions yet.

I'd suggest reading the authentication flow and the example PHP SDK authentication flow, see the following links:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication2/

Comment: Hi Coulton,
I forgot to mention that the USECASE1 is also called outside the if block and through logs i have checked that USECASE1 that is being called is the one outside if block. So, the $me is never being set. As i said the flow goes outside the if block then to USECASE1 and then the $facebook->getUser() works fine.